# how can I start Windows XP with the network disabled

Tags: windows, networking, windows-xp, boot

Is it possible to start Windows-XP with the network connections disabled, and to manually enable network access only when e.g. getting the email or starting the browser?

Comment: Just unplug the cable

Comment: _Just unplug the cable_
Thought of that, but isn't very practical for the cable being under my desk...

Answer (score 1):

You can try setting the services for networking to manual? You would have to write some sort of script to enable them only when you open a browser though.

I think you should rethink why you would want to do this, and come up with a different solution?

Comment: The reason is additional security. Being offline is always a stronger protection than a firewall alone can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to start Windows-XP with the network connections disabled, for this you must change the service state to manual or disabled...
By default it is impossible to append enable or disable function to email or internet browser, but you can create a batch file which will do it for you

for example:
sc config service_name start= disabled (This state disables the service)
sc config service_name start= enabled (This state will enable the given service)

so you can create start service bat and use this commands